# Outlook 2010 no longer allows me to Ctrl+V, T to paste plain text (and more)

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-outlook-2010, copy-paste, microsoft-office-2013

I recently installed Office 2013 and then realized that Outlook 2013 doesn't support Exchange 2003 (we're in the process of upgrading to Exchange 2013). So I uninstalled Outlook 2013 and re-installed 2010.

Now, I have the following issues when using Outlook (and they are likely related):

- When pasting, I used to be able to use the key combo `Ctrl+V, T` to paste plaint text. Now, I cannot - but I can still right click and choose to paste plain text. If I try to use the key combo `Ctrl+V, T`, the copied text is pasted (with source formatting) and then I get the letter "t". See the screen shot below.

[image]

- Automatic spell check no longer works. I can manually run spell check but as I type, my errors are not underlined as they used to be. I have the "check spelling as I type" option enabled (although it is grayed out/disabled which seems strange).

[image]

I tried to repair my Office 2010 installation but the problem persists.

Comment: This sounds like a settings configuration problem.  Have you enabled spelling to be enabled all the time?

Comment: @Ramhound - That feature is checked but disabled, which is a strange state. It seems like I perhaps have some component missing. I updated my question with a screenshot.